# Python. Удаление элемента списка в for внутри if

Tags: python, список

```
win_row = [(0,1,2),
           (3,4,5),
           (6,7,8),
           (0,3,6),
           (1,4,7),
           (2,5,8),
           (0,4,8),
           (2,4,6)]
MOVES = [4,0,2,7]
for i in win_row:
    for j in MOVES:
        if j in i:
            print ("\n", j, "-", i, "кортеж", win_row)
            win_row.remove(i)
```

Удаляю элемент i, но в следующей итерации переменная не обнуляется - цикл повторно ищет удаленный кортеж, пытается его снова удалить и выдает ошибку, т. к. его уже нет. Почему после удаление win_row.remove(i), сама переменная i не обнуляется?

Comment: `break` нужно поставить после `win_row.remove(i)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы так делал:

```
win_row = [(0,1,2),
           (3,4,5),
           (6,7,8),
           (0,3,6),
           (1,4,7),
           (2,5,8),
           (0,4,8),
           (2,4,6)]
MOVES = [4,0,2,7]

from copy import deepcopy
tmp = deepcopy(win_row)
for j in MOVES:
    for i in win_row:
        if j in i:
            print ("\n", j, "-", i, "кортеж", win_row)
            tmp.remove(i)
    win_row = deepcopy(tmp)
```

> Почему после удаление win_row.remove(i), сама переменная i не обнуляется?

Потому что нет такого условия. На примере `(0,1,2)`
`for j in MOVES` проверяет сначала `4`, затем `0` - тут он удаляет `(0,1,2)`, но продолжает проверять `2`, `7` - так как условия выхода из цикла нет.

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что i - это ссылка на первый элемент списка, т. е. (0,1,2). Тогда после удаления первого элемента списка, удаляется кортеж (0,1,2), а переменная i, которая на него ссылалась, должна принять значение None? Т. е. после удаления (0,1,2), поиск 2,7 должен продолжиться в None,

Comment: @СергейП Переменные, созданные в выражении `expression` цикла `for ... in`, продолжают существовать после завершения цикла. Как и любые локальные переменные прекращают существовать после выхода из области видимости, включающей их. Цитата из Саммерфилда.

Comment: Следовательно, `i` - не ссылка на кортеж, а локальная переменная со значением кортежа.

Comment: Большое спасибо за разъяснения. Просто и понятно. Страдаю второй день, не мог понять. Сделаю себе заметку ознакомиться с книгой Саммерфилда.

Comment: слишком сложно для такого простого действия

Answer (score 2):

```
win_row[:] = [r for r in win_row if not any(i in r for i in MOVES)]
```

Comment: Элегантно всё таки